# Is there an easy way to convert all mysql timestamps to UTC?

Tags: mysql

I've adopted a rather old mysql database and all of the timestamp, datetime, and time columns have been set with `time_zone = "+05:00";`.

Obviously I could write a script to adjust each column individually, however, the database is very large and this will take an eternity.

Is there any easier way to remove 5 hours from each column with those types from all tables? I figured all developers knew to store them as UTC but I guess I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
CONVERT_TZ('2010-01-22 12:00:00','CET','UTC')
```

OR any of them you can try

```
CONVERT_TZ(your_datetime_field,'SYSTEM','UTC') CONVERT_TZ(your_datetime_field,@@global.time_zone,'UTC')
```

Comment: I try this `CONVERT_TZ(event.start_datetime,'US/EASTERN','UTC');` and I get the error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONVERT_TZ(event.start_datetime,'US/EASTERN','UTC')' at line 1`. I am using MySQL version 5.6.41.